# Skype for Business IM log archive with no Exchange license

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, skype-for-business-2016

Is it possible to have IM conversation log from Skype for Business without the Exchange license?

As the conversation history is stored in the user's mailbox in Exchange, is there a way to have that, with only the Skype for Business license assigned to some users, in Office365? (No Exchange license).

Answer (score 0):

You need to distinguish between two different features:

- **IM Archiving**: which is the ability to log almost all activities in the Skype for Business using Exchange "In-Place Hold" feature. this is enabled and managed by an administrator.
- **Conversation History**: which is the ability to search through past conversation using Outlook, this is enabled and managed by end user.

Both features requires an Exchange Mailbox to function, Exchange license is a must in this case. Till this point I'm not aware of any special Office 365 license that is available for any of the above features.

References:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/skype-for-business-online-security-and-archiving.aspx
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-a-previous-Skype-for-Business-conversation-18892eba-5f18-4281-8c87-fd48bd72e6a2?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US